# Disable caching YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, html, flash, youtube

YouTube achieved quite a feat when they made youtube videos work with cache. However, this is causing a problem on my ajax site and would like to know if there is a way to disable youtube videos being cached. Especially in Internet Explorer.

I cannot disable caching for the whole page as I need caching to work for images and other content for speed reasons.

Any one know any solutions?

Comment: what kind of problem is it causing?

Comment: When we reload the page each time it takes IE longer to start playing the video. Sometimes it never plays and an error comes back from youtube saying the video is not available. If I clear cache, it loads again fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure that each time user is downloading from an unique URL. Your player code contains something like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/sMiUpl_6jI0?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB
```

That is URL to the YouTube player. All you have to do is add new randomly generated token at the end, like (PHP example):

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/sMiUpl_6jI0?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;noCachePlease=<?php echo uniqid() ?>
```

Each time you visit the page that URL will contain an unique token so the browser won't use any cache mechanisms.

Comment: Great idea, I'm doing this with ajax pages that IE caches. Don't know why I didn't think of using it here. Easily done with JS. youtubeUrl += '&noCache=' + Math.random(); I'll test it out.

Comment: After testing this out, it does not appear to work.  It may have worked at some time, but I can understand why youtube would want to "fix" this so that they don't waste bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

This meta tags could help:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

I believe the second one is what you are looking for. Look it up, for sure some one has a nice tutorial.

As I recall, it is not possible to clear it, unless user does by his own means.

cheers

Comment: Unfortunately the HTTP headers won't affect flash videos caching behavior, I mean, try putting a simple SWF in an HTML page and you can see that it will always be cached no matter what HTTP headers you set in that page. What you suggested works for normal web content such as images but not flash files.