# View-only video (No way to download, only playable)

Tags: flash, html, video, youtube, readonly

I'm creating PHP based web project in which students can login and watch tutorials. The service is paid, so I want to prevent downloading video files from website (and sharing for free).

In other words, every user can only watch videos on website, no way to download.

For this purpose, I was searching for secure HTML5 or Flash based web video player that doesn't cache video or deletes all temp video files after playing it.

What I want to get is, something like youtube does: deletes temp files after watching video.

Is there any way to do it? Any suggestions?

What about embeding video from youtube and making it "read-only" (no way to download)?! Is that possible?

## OR

can this piece of code help me to not to cache video?

```
<!-- no cache headers -->
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<!-- end no cache headers -->
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: "View-only" might be a better title. YouTube fights a running battle against downloader apps. No idea how they currently do it but it's probably a very carefully designed crypto system.

Comment: @Potatoswatter fixed. Thx for off-topic suggestion)))

Comment: Might be related to :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840798/disable-caching-youtube-videos

Comment: Your users will simply use a tool that acts like your player and then downloads and saves the video. Don't waste time on money on protecting the videos, it's completely useless.

Answer (score 3):

It is simply not possible. You can try to obscure the process... but ultimately the video data needs to reach the users browser and there is no way to stop them storing it. If YouTube, Grooveshark and numerous other big streaming sites can not prevent users ripping content then you will not come up with a solution.

My VPN even has a function built in to grab media content before it reaches my browser. Apart from that there is a whole host of tools, browser plugins and sites dedicated to ripping videos.

Comment: "You can try to obscure the process" how? )) And youtube already does it, try to watch movie, at the end all temp files will be deleted from browser cache. All media files are only available while they're playing. Not after in youtube system

Comment: I am not sure how they do it. But to be blunt it is not worth the time and effort. People will pirate... I suggest you make the videos a part of a bigger service... something which can not be simply downloaded. Better still make the videos free and secure sponsorship from another related service.

Comment: How about just cleaning temp folder after video playback so that there can not stay any played video. Just as youtube does. I think it's possible, but how?!))

Comment: Would you users not prefer to be able to download the videos and play them on their tablets / phones? I know I enjoy watching my Zendcasts on the subway. I think you should re think your business model - just as Holywood is having to.

Comment: I need help in model. I mean if I share them for free, 1 person will pay for and share for free with others. I really don't want it to happen

Comment: Maybe you can find a sponsor? A paid service which would like to brand the videos as theirs? or to have a 'Sponsored by logo as the end'? What are the videos about?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from any in-code protection you can provide, you'll obviously want to make sure that your site cannot be directory listed!

You might be able to protect against downloading the video file itself but I don't see how you can protect against screencasting software like CamStudio. Yes, the quality of the resulting video and audio won't be great, but they'd still be able to get hold it.

Comment: I'm working with camtasia. But I don't know, if there is way to secure video with inbuilt functionality

Comment: How about just cleaning temp folder after video playback so that there can not stay any played video. Just as youtube does. I think it's possible, but how?!))

Comment: I believe capture software works on hooking into the video memory and audio feeds rather than accessing the video file itself. The same problem exists with photos and graphics. The user just has to do a screen capture and they have a version of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Seems rather difficult . . . Users can always use programs to capture your stream or use screen capture.

May be the following links can be of some interest. Not sure if they will work in your case.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/protecting_video_rtmpe.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/digital_media_protection.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Streaming

Edit: See a related post [Disable caching YouTube videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840798/disable-caching-youtube-videos)

If you want to stop illegal distribution of your video, you can try putting a 
watermark on your videos.

Comment: How about just cleaning temp folder after video playback so that there can not stay any played video. Just as youtube does. I think it's possible, but how?!))

Comment: make sure you keep changing the links for the video dynamically..thats how youtube does it.. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840798/disable-caching-youtube-videos